# diskutil resizeVolume noob

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

- Back story :

After I installed Windows with Bootcamp, I wanted to make **another** partition where I'll install Linux, but couldn't do that from `Disk Utility` because I found on the internet that *Yosemite* can't partition Logical Volumes (or something like that). So I had to use the command line.

- The problem :

I resized a volume `disk0s2` from 400G to 350G to make room for Linux with this command :

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 350g
```

And forgot to make a new partition with the new free space. How do I access and format it (It has to be Linux compatible) ?

**NB :** When installing Linux it doesn't detect the free unformatted space

**Logs :**

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         399.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                100.0 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *340.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 AC56F919-322B-49D0-9AFF-4718DFBC9021
                                 Unencrypted


$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group CCAF5997-E705-494E-9ADB-A0C76B62D3ED
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         399248105472 B (399.2 GB)
    Free Space:   58895785984 B (58.9 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 0E48CCED-435C-4FBA-949C-C28DAA859CA6
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     399248105472 B (399.2 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family D4956F33-E196-460B-8E9E-CB7365BB4275
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume AC56F919-322B-49D0-9AFF-4718DFBC9021
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          339999997952 B (340.0 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: Could you run `diskutil list` on your Mac and update your question with the output?

Comment: It would also be useful to include the model of your Mac and which linux distribution (fedora, ubuntu, etc) you are going to install.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Have you considered running Linux in a virtual machine? It's easier to deal with and can be run along side OS X.

Comment: If you are going to do this, the first thing I would do is get rid of core storage. You do not need it unless you want to encrypt your OS X partition.  What you have done so far is create empty space in your core storage partition. This is why linux can not find it during installation.

Comment: Not a big fan of virtual machines.  
@DavidAnderson Should I revert back to HFS+ ? Knowing that CoreStorage contains files for the actual Mac OS + Free space I'm gonna use for Linux

Comment: Yes, if you can, revert back to a hfs+ volume. If you install linux between OS  X and Windows, then the partition indices with not be sequential. This means the Disk Utility application will not display the partitions properly. You can use a free third party tool to fix this, but if this can cause a BIOS/MBR install of Windows to not boot. Most Boot Camp Assistant installs are done this way, unless you have a fairly new Mac. Also, certain linux's installers can become confused if Windows uses BIOS/MBR while OS X is using EFI/GPT. You may have to install Windows after installing Linux.